# Items in ListBox not automatically updating

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

The problem is that the user interface (the ListBox) is not updated when new items enter its collection. I've a ListBox which is defined as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ui_UserList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="ui_UserList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding chatUsers}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,179,10,81" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding nickname}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="42" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The itemsource `ChatUsers` is an `ObservableCollection`. This was originally designed as an application for Windows Phone 8, where the ListBox equivalent works as expected (it updates when an item enters the collection).

Is there something about the ListBox that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I needed to set the DataContext explicitly even though it never complained about it. 
The only change is this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ui_UserList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="ui_UserList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding chatUsers}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,179,10,81" DataContext="{StaticResource ChatUsersViewModel}">
.....
</ListBox>
```